# SceneKit application dumps when swiping up from lower edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I'm recently creating an application using the new SceneKit framework for iOS and I'm wondering about a weird bug. Because I didn't know if I was causing this bug, I created a new project and it was still there. 
It just occurs when the iPad (I'm using a physical testing device) is in landscape right mode when swiping from the "home-button-sided" edge to the center of the screen. The compiler gives following information:

> 2014-06-20 18:22:12.066 Game[727:60518] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2afea2bf 0x37ee0d2f 0x2af0aee5 0x2e846c97 0x2e5cd22b 0x2afb1e47 0x2afb1257 0x2afaf8bd 0x2aefcfb1 0x2aefcdc3 0x320782c9 0x2e62ca1d 0x7fd25 0x38461aaf)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

It works properly in any other device orientation. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. [Have you filed it?](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I just wanted to know before if there is a known fix.